# Spring jpa returning specific column without nativeQuery

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I trying to select from database specific column only

```
public interface ItemRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Item,String> {

  @Query("SELECT i.id FROM Item i where i.id =?1")
  Optional<Item> getit(String id);
}
```

But instead of returning Object `Item` it returns `String` (the id value).

How Can I return the object? (I can't add any constructors to it)

p.s. if I use `nativeQuery` it does work.

Answer (score 0):

This query in `JQL` can be simpler.

```
@Query("SELECT i FROM Item i where i.id =?1")
Optional<Item> getit(String id);
```

Or even

```
@Query("FROM Item where id =?1")
Optional<Item> getit(String id);
```

However, since you are already using JPA, you don't need to define *any* method with a `@Query` annotation.

`findById` is already defined.

```
Optional<Item> itemOpt = itemRepository.findById(id);
```